# How can I skip execution of the parent of an included file (but not the parent's parent)

Tags: php, include, return

I have three files:

- outer.php
- inner.php
- innermost.php

`inner.php` is included inside `outer.php` and `innermost.php` is further included inside `inner.php`

`innermost.php` has a condition in it that needs to stop execution of `inner.php` but not `outer.php`

Calling `return` will end execution of `innermost.php` but not `inner.php`

In other words, how can I skip execution from an included file of the immediate file it was included in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose you could check the return value of `innermost.php`:

```
if ((include 'inermost.php') != true) {
    return false;
}
```

Do make sure to `return true;` in `innermost.php`